# How To Display Service Flow Direction Graphics on User Side( JS API or AGO)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 I am publishing a Service which has Flow Directions on it like

[image]

but when consuming in ArcGIS online or even on ArcGIS for JavaScript API Application I am getting  lines without Arrow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.23 of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, the SimpleLineSymbol supports displaying arrow markers on the beginning and/or ending vertices of a polyline.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/whats_new.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/simplelinesymbol-amd.html#setmarker

```
  lineSymbol.setMarker({
    style: "arrow",
    placement: "end"
  });
```